# How to Use @JsonView Annotation for nested Object ( DTOs)

Tags: java, spring-boot, serialization, backend, deserialization

I want to use @JsonView In Nested DTOs.

My UserDTO looks like this

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class UserDTO {
    @JsonView(value = {Views.UserProtected.class, Views.UserPrivate.class})
    Long userId;
    @JsonView(value = {Views.UserProtected.class})
    String firstname;
    @JsonView(value = {Views.UserProtected.class})
    String lastname;
    @JsonView(value = {Views.UserProtected.class})
    String email;
    @JsonView(value = {Views.UserPrivate.class})
    String password;
}
```

and My appointmentDTO looks like this

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class GetAppointmentResponseDTO {
        private Long appointmentId;
        private String title;
        private String description;

        @JsonView(Views.UserProtected.class)
        private UserDTO scheduledBy;

        @JsonView(Views.UserProtected.class)
        private UserDTO scheduledWith;

        private List<AppointmentInstance> appointmentInstances;
        private AppointmentType type;
        private String location;
}
```

when i am fetching appointment data UserDTO inside AppointmentDTO also has password field inside it, i want to include protected fields mention in views inside it. how should i approach it.